# replacing NA's in one column with the product of two other columns

Tags: r

In a column of 7000 rows there are 11 NA's. I want to replace those NA's with the product of two other columns in my data frame

The column with NA's is `TOTALCHARGES` and the two columns I want to multiply are `TENURE` and `MONTHLYCHARGES`.

Answer (score 1):

Find the indices of the missing data:

```
na.vals <- which(is.na(your_data$TOTALCHARGES))
```

Modify the relevant elements of `TOTALCHARGES` (within the data set):

```
your_data <- transform(your_data,
       TOTALCHARGES=replace(TOTALCHARGES,na.vals,
           TENURE[na.vals]*MONTHLYCHARGES[na.vals]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (assuming `df` is your `data.frame`)?

```
df[is.na(df$TOTALCHARGES), "TOTALCHARGES"] <- df[is.na(df$TOTALCHARGES), "TENURE"] * df[is.na(df$TOTALCHARGES), "MONTHLYCHARGES"]
```